Как закрепить окно камеры в unity?

Как закрепить это окно при переключении на другой объект?

В unity кастумное расположение окон интерфейса... обычно об этом упоминают практически в каждой первой серии видео обозревая редактор. Окно Game можно расположить где угодно, что бы оно не было табом вместе с Scene. А замок на инспекторе не для этого.

Оказалось нужно выбрать камеру и в инспекторе нажать на замок, тогда окно закрепляется.
